# How to Remove open bracket from JSON Response

Tags: android, json

I have one json string like below.

```
oncomptetion({
  "competition": [
  {
      "CompetitionID": "7b47afgwi2017odi",
      "CompetitionName": "AFGHANISTAN IN WESTINDIES ODI SERIES 2017",
      "DivisionID": "1",
      "DivisionName": "1 Division",
      "MappingCompName": "",
      "CompetitionType": "One Day Match"
    },
    {
      "CompetitionID": "7b4785be057b448f",
      "CompetitionName": "AFGHANISTAN IN WESTINDIES T20I SERIES 2017",
      "DivisionID": "1",
      "DivisionName": "1 Division",
      "MappingCompName": "",
      "CompetitionType": "T20 Match"
    }]
})
```

I want to delete/remove the first and last open brackets and Including **oncomptetion** this name from string.

Please help me

Comment: this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: From where you are getting this invalid JSON??

Comment: Considering that is a string. if yes then remove charAt(0) and charAt(last position)

Comment: No,this url developed in javascript

Comment: @RameshYogu instead using patches in the code, try to get the JSON response from the API

Comment: Simple. `String finalString = sourceString.substring(sourceString.indexOf("{"), sourceString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);`

Comment: thank you @when the morning comes

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get valid `Json`

```
    String json="your Srting"; //unformatted string


    String output = json.replace("oncomptetion(", ""); //removing  oncomptetion(
    String finalJson=  output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);   //removing last string )

    System.out.println(""+finalJson);
```

output :

```
    {  "competition": [
      {
          "CompetitionID": "7b47afgwi2017odi",
          "CompetitionName": "AFGHANISTAN IN WESTINDIES ODI SERIES 2017",
          "DivisionID": "1",
          "DivisionName": "1 Division",
          "MappingCompName": "",
          "CompetitionType": "One Day Match"
        },
        {
          "CompetitionID": "7b4785be057b448f",
          "CompetitionName": "AFGHANISTAN IN WESTINDIES T20I SERIES 2017",
          "DivisionID": "1",
          "DivisionName": "1 Division",
          "MappingCompName": "",
          "CompetitionType": "T20 Match"
        }]
    }
```